# Use command grep and locate

Tags: linux, search, command-line, grep, locate

How I can make the grep command locate certain words in the files specified by the routes found by the locate command?

```
locate my.cnf | grep user
```

(I want that grep command search the word "user" on the files found for locate command)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of a pipe, use command replacement:

```
grep user `locate my.cnf`
```

Comment: I like this one better than the `xargs` approach below because it maintains grep's highlighting

Comment: @moeso: You can get grep to always give color output with `--color=always`.

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
locate my.cnf | xargs grep user
```

Comment: This option is correct, but Matt responded first and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Jhonathan - if the result is fairly small, matt's works. If the result can be arbitrarily large, you should prefer `xargs`.

Comment: For options necessary for spaces in file paths, see answer of Marko Kudjerski below.

Answer (score 2):

In order to play nice with situations when locate results have spaces in names, you could do this

```
locate -0 my.cnf | xargs -n1 -0 grep user
```

Comment: Shows the same output three times

Comment: Without any switches `grep` automatically outputs all of the matching lines (your file likely has multiple lines that match). If you wish to show line numbers in front of them you could use `-n` switch for grep. Otherwise, you could have it output only the first match for every file with `-m 1` or only the name of the file that matches with `-l`.

Comment: `locate -0` is indeed necessary if file paths contain spaces.
 
However, in bash, to see the full path of the file, I have to add `-H` to grep, like so:

`locate -0 *.tex | xargs -n1 -0 grep -H user`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `grep user $(locate my.cnf)` is what you're looking for, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Note that this will crash and burn if that `locate` command returns too much data. Command line size is not infinite.